# Getting a list of lists for all elements in list of lists greater than a certain threshold

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]
```

Now I want to make a new list of lists containing elements greater than 5. It should look like

```
k=[[],[6],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094459/find-all-elements-and-indices-larger-than-threshold-in-list-of-lists) but it returns a list like `j=[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]`. How to get a list that looks like `k` from `l`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definately use List Comp here.

```
k = [[i for i in subl if i > 5] for subl in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` function along with list comprehension.

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]
>>> [list(filter(lambda x: x > 5, i)) for i in l]
[[], [6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```